# Redeploying Azure MVC site makes "unresponsive" Service Bus code start working again. Why?

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, servicebus

I'm doing my first implementation of Service Bus in MVC.

- The MVC web app in Azure sends messages to the service bus
- An on-premise console app on the customer's premises picks them up.

The customer's network is incredibly unreliable. There's nothing we can do about it. Hence using Service Bus. The outages on their network "seem" to be causing the Service Bus to silently "die". It may be unrelated. It stops sending messages to the queue. No errors. But redeploying the MVC app which presumably restarts the app pool resolves it.

This code gets called from a synchronous Web API method and stops working about once a day with no errors.

```
        queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName);
        var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));



        var task = Task.Run(async () => { await queueClient.SendAsync(message); });
        task.Wait();
```

I don't have much experience with async code and suspect there's is something wrong with that or I should be using a worker process. Although I'm new to that as well.

Cheers, Chris.

Comment: Just to be clear, your MVC and console app both are deployed on-prem and you are using Azure Service bus for communication ? And once a day your MVC stops sending message to ASB ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I don't have notifications switched on for this app. No the MVC app is on Azure and the console app is on premises. We ended up going for a Logic App solution. But I'd love to know what I was doing wrong. The MVC app isn't a cloud project if that helps. Switching on notifications now. Cheers.